# Обособляется ли "то есть" в значении "точнее", "значит"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова, словосочетания, частица

Скажите, в данном случае сочетание "то есть" выступает в роли вводного  (можно заменить по смыслу на "значит", "точнее") или же всё равно является частицей и не должно выделяться запятыми?

*Она ушла в лес по грибы. Ушла(,) то есть(,) к нему, конечно же.*

Comment: Я бы обособлял. В такой позиции "то есть" воспринимается как вводное сочетание.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Она ушла в лес по грибы. **Ушла то есть к нему**, конечно же.*

Думаю, что здесь использована **инверсия союза ТО ЕСТЬ**. При прямом порядке слов: *Она ушла в лес по грибы. **То есть** ушла к нему, конечно же.*

Дело в том, что союз [**ТО ЕСТЬ**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?id=58_733&layout=item) по правилам **не обособляется** и вводным словом не бывает, в справочнике по пунктуации это **подчеркивается особо**.

1. Союз. Присоединяет слова или предложения, поясняющие или уточняющие высказанную мысль; то же, что «а именно, другими словами».

*В этой книге рассказывается о сказочной стране, в которой жили малыши и малышки, **то есть** крошечные мальчики и девочки, или, как их иначе называли, коротышки.* Н. Носов, Незнайка в Солнечном городе. *Имея прямое отношение к кухне, питался по норме № 5, **то есть** по летной норме.* В. Войнович, Жизнь и необычайные приключения солдата Ивана Чонкина.

! После союза «то есть» **запятая не ставится.**

Это именно союз, **а не частица**. Сравнить: *«Вывозили? То есть как вывозили?» – спросила Регина Петровна, вдруг побледнев.* Здесь частица усиливает эмоциональность ответной реплики.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ** (по комментариям)

В современной речи союз ТО ЕСТЬ не обособляется, но **в старых изданиях**, в том числе у классиков, можно встретить обособление этого слова. Скорее всего, оно использовалось как **междометное выражение** и передавало характерные особенности речи персонажа. В современной литературе обособление будет считаться авторским (ненормированным) вариантом.

Кроме того, в указанном предложении избыточное количество **запятых**, поэтому запись (тонирование речи) вряд ли будет понята читателем нужным образом.

В качестве вариантов редактирования можно предложить следующее:

*Ушла... то есть к нему, конечно же. Ушла, то есть... к нему, конечно же.*

Здесь нарушения правил не будет.

Comment: Здесь "то есть" теряет свою союзную окраску, как мне кажется, и склоняется к вводному сочетанию "стало быть". Такое выделение "то есть" встречается нередко в дореволюционной прозе как разговорное, см. Нацкорпус: "― А точно, надо правду сказать, ежели бы, то есть, так глуп не был наш степной народ..."; "В молодости в самом деле вольготнее будто бы жили, потому дешевисть была во всем, милый ты мой, самая, то есть, добродетельная, благорастворение воздухов истинно райское"; "а против нашего, то есть, миру, известно, господская воля; потому вы наши отцы" (последнее -- Тургенев, как-никак).

Comment: В ваших примерах "то есть" похоже на междометие, на приговорку, характерную для речи определенного лица. Междометие, соответственно, обособляется, и я не могу исключить этот вариант, он тоже возможен. Но только это ни в коем случае не вводное слово. Кроме того, запятых уж очень много, так что текст понимается с трудом. Если это действительно выбор автора, то он должен обратить на это внимание и понимать функцию слова в этом предложении.

Comment: да, междометие -- это вернее. Что касается нагромождения запятых, то они хорошо передают живую речь. Конечно, надо и не перебарщивать.

Comment: А если считать ТО ЕСТЬ частицей и не обособлять? Это тоже будет авторским решением (такого значения в словаре нет).

Comment: может быть. Но мне кажется, что в примере из вопроса запятые хорошо слышатся, то есть это "интонационные" знаки.

Comment: Ну ладно, тогда "разрешаю" оставить интонационные знаки. :))  Персонаж, возможно, волнуется, поэтому говорить не очень внятно. Но это все надо видеть по контексту.

Comment: "Вы... это самое... того... / Когда вы говорите, / то, значит, это... как его. / Ну, в общем, не тяните" (из детской книжечки) :)

Comment: А нам здесь можно так говорить, ну...это самое... в комментариях? :))

Comment: Максимум -- придёт МаркИз и выпнет в чат)